# How to Iterate between colunns and rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I am running the following forumula:

```
=IF(INDEX(C$2:$2, 1, ROW(1:1)),CONCATENATE(B$2,"-",INDEX(C$1:$1, 1, ROW(1:1))))
```

On the following table

[image]

Basically, If a value is present in column C2, I am returning the value + the value of B2. I would like to do this for all the columns up to O2, however, once I reach column O2, I would like to move to the next row and have the process start with a new row. How would I do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C2:O<>"", "♦"&B2:B&"-"&C1:O1, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Appreciate it! Any chance you can share some insight into how you came up with this?
Just to add on, I would like to not return a value if no value is present in a row, so for F2, I would like to return false.

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C2:O<>"", "♦"&B2:B&"-"&C1:O1, "♦FALSE")),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))))`

Comment: sadly, even if the answer solved the OP's issue, it got downvoted by someone who couldn't come up with the solution and OP can't accept it from the new account